# VSCode - Remove circle next to terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

I noticed today that there is a weird symbol being drawn next to the terminal in VSCode. It looks like it's purpose is to indicate where the next input starts. How do I turn this off? It is driving me nuts. I went threw all the options in the terminal page but I don't see anything.....

Image showing the weird circle:

[image]

Comment: they've been messing with this stuff. Here's some stuff from the release notes that touches on the general area. I am not sure what that thing you are pointing at is. https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_69#_consistent-format-for-messages-from-vs-code

Comment: Thanks, that got me in the right general area. For anyone else that finds this post, the feature is called "Command Decorations". Searching for that in the command palette will give you options to turn it off / adjust the look. Thanks David!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad you found the root cause (and gave us all the search terms to Google).

Comment: I will also add that these symbols seem to be there to indicate if the command was successful or not (an exit code of 0 will have a green circle next to it, any other will be red, and an unused prompt will be empty like OP's screenshot). I actually found this behavior interesting and was googling how it was enabled because I would like to have this in regular shells as well :D It seems this is VS-specific functionality, but similar functionality can be enabled in ZSH as explained [here](https://codeburst.io/adding-an-octopus-to-the-zsh-prompt-56edf2e9bcad)

Comment: They're so annoying, thanks for asking

Answer (score 17):

Saw these same dots this morning, found them pretty annoying.

These are the settings related to the dots

[image: 1]

I got rid of them by setting Integrated > Shell Integration: Decorations Enabled to never. This is in User settings under Features > Terminal.

Comment: Ctrl + shift + p -> open settings (ui) gets you to the page with a lot of settings. I also see it looks like you took care of this in the comments, whoops!